# What is a BitVector and how to use it as return in Breeze Scala?

Tags: scala, bitvector

I am doing a comparison between two `BreezeDenseVectors` with the following way `a :< b` and what i get as a return is a `BitVector`.
I haven't worked again with this and everything i read about it, was not helpful enough.

Can anyone explain to me how they work?

Additionally, by printing the output, i get: `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }`. What is this supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [BitVectorTest.scala](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/blob/master/math/src/test/scala/breeze/linalg/BitVectorTest.scala) for more detail usage.
Basically, `a :< b` gives you a BitVector, which indicates which elements in a smaller than the ones in b.
For example `val a = DenseVector[Int](4, 9, 3); val b = DenseVector[Int](8, 2, 5); a  :< b` will gives you `BitVector(0, 2)`, it means that `a(0) < b(0)` and `a(2) < b(2)`, which is correct.